# MessageDialog in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtkmm

In my current project I need to perform some calculations when a specific button is pressed, and while I perform these calculations, I want to show a `Gtk::MessageDialog` that simply states that calculations are being performed. So, I initialize the MessageDialog like this (for the moment just ignore that I actually don't need the pointer here):

```
Gtk::MessageDialog *waitdialog;
Gtk::MessageDialog dia("Processing", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_INFO, Gtk::BUTTONS_NONE, true);
dia.set_title("Wait.");
dia.set_transient_for(*(Gtk::Window *)this);
waitdialog = &dia;
```

Next I want to start a separate thread with the dialog:

```
std::thread dialog_thread(wait_dialog,waitdialog);
```

The wait_dialog method is defined as follows:

```
void wait_dialog(Gtk::MessageDialog *dialog){
  dialog->run();
}
```

The problem now is, that even though the main window is darkened (because of set_transient_for), the message dialog is not visible. However, when I don't start a seperate thread, but just call `waitdialog->run()` instead, this will show the dialog properly (but will result in a loop).

So, the question is: why does the workaround with the separate thread not work? I can't make any sense of that :-(

Comment: Are you allowed to show UI outside the main thread? And what are you hoping to achieve by this? A modal dialog in a thread just blocks that thread. Do you want to block that thread and let the main thread remain responsive?

Comment: when i connect the button with my calculations, the ui just freezes (which is a bad idea because the user might get the impression that the program is broken) My idea was to open a MessageDialog (without buttons), that just states that the program is doing some calculations and to release that MessageDialog when the calculations are done. I can't open that MessageDialog in the main thread, because then it is blocked and I can't do my calculations, so I wanted to put it in it's own thread...

Comment: my solution now is the other way around: to put the calculations into it's own thread and let the main thread get blocked... however, I get the feeling that I should look for yet a better solution, since I still have to pass the dialog to the calculations thread to have it at my hands to release it later)...

Comment: That doesn't sound right at all. Don't block the main thread. It's for UI. Put the long running stuff in different threads.

Answer (score 1):

GUI components *are required* to stay in the GUI loop.  Your long running calculations belong in the thread.  The calculation thread then signals back to the GUI thread to close the modal dialog.  Also, you should use glib threads instead of std::threads.  Here's how I would structure program:

```
// in header, member var dispatcher used to signal GUI thread
// and our member var thread
Glib::Dispatcher m_signalDone;
Glib::Thread* m_someThread;

...

// in constructor, hook up dispatcher event
m_signalDone.connect(sigc::mem_fun(this, &MyClass::OnDone));

...

// later when ready to kick off thread...
// show dialog or progess bar or something and kick off thread...
m_someThread = Glib::Thread::create(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::CalcMethod), true);

...

void MyClass::CalcMethod()
{
   // do your long running stuff...

   // when done signal completion back to GUI
   m_signalDone.emit();
}

...

void MyClass::OnDone()
{
    // clean up dialog or progress bar or whatever

    // kill thread
    m_currentBackUpThread->join();
    m_currentBackUpThread = NULL;
}
```

Comment: thanks :-) Your answer made it clearer for me (in theory), though I still have to try to implement it that way. Now it's a little late, so I'll try tomorrow, but I'm already a big step ahead... :-)